# SSIS Power Query Source OData Connection Not Working

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odata, etl, powerquery

I'm trying to use a Power Query Source connector in SSIS (VS 2017) to get data from an OData data source.

I can create an OData connector and connect to it ok. When I try to look at the columns after entering my query I get the following error "**could not load file or assembley 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.NetFX35.V7'**  (see attached image):

[image]

I've downloaded the nuget package directly but I'm not sure how to install it or where to install? Is it possible to connect to an OData source using the Power Query connector?

Comment: To install the NuGet package, from the `Tools` menu, select `NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console`. In the `Package Manager Console` window, type: `Install-Package Microsoft.OData.Edm -Version 7.4.0`.

Comment: Nuget Package Manager is not available for SQL Server Data tools projects.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version installed? (not visual studio)

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that I didn't find anything related to this error online, but I will suggest some possible solutions:

#### (1) Run package in 32-bit mode

Try to change `Run64bitRuntime` property to `False` in the project properties:

- [Switch package from 64bit to 32bit](https://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/09/swtich-package-from-64bit-to-32bit.html)

#### (2) Install ODATA Components

If you are using a prior version of SQL Server 2016 *(if SQL 2016 or newer, these components are installed by default)* , try to install ODATA components from SQL Server feature pack, as example:

- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

#### (3) Check that you are selecting the proper TargetServerVersion

Check that you have selected the relevant SQL Server version within the project properties:

- [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)